# Tweepy won't install on python 3.7; shows "syntax error"

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, python-3.7

Before I begin, I'd like to preface that I'm relatively new to python, and haven't had to use it much before this little project of mine. I'm trying to make a twitter bot as part of an art project, and I can't seem to get tweepy to import. I'm using macOS High Sierra and Python 3.7. I first installed tweepy by using

```
pip3 install tweepy
```

and this appeared to work, as I'm able to find the tweepy files in finder. However, when I simply input

```
import tweepy
```

into the IDLE, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jacobhill/Documents/CicadaCacophony.py", line 1, in <module>
  import tweepy
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  from tweepy.streaming import Stream, StreamListener
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 358
  def _start(self, async):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea on how to remedy this? I've looked at other posts on here and the other errors seem to be along the lines of "tweepy module not found", so I don't know what to do with my error. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `async` as an identifier [has been deprecated since Python 3.5, and became an error in Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#deprecation-plans), because it's a keyword.

This Tweepy bug was [reported on 16 Mar](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1017), and [fixed on 12 May](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1042), but [there hasn't been a new release yet](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1063). Which is why, as [the repo's main page says](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy):

> Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5 & 3.6 are supported.

---

For the time being, you can install the development version:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
```

Or, since you've already installed an earlier version:

```
pip3 install --upgrade git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
```

---

You could also follow the instructions from the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
python3 setup.py install
```

However, this will mean `pip` may not fully understand what you've installed.

Answer (score 4):

In Python3.7, [`async`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#async) became a reserved word (as can be seen in *whats new* section [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html)) and therefore cannot be used as argument. This is why this `Syntax Error` is raised.

That said, and following `tweetpy`s official GitHub ([here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy)), only

> Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5 & 3.6 are supported.

---

However, if you really must use Python3.7, there is a workaround. Following [this](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1017) suggestion, you can

> open streaming.py and replace `async` with `async_`

and it should work

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. Given that the bug has been fixed upstream (but not released), I think it's probably better to install from the repo than to fix it locally, but I don't see anything wrong with explaining how to fix it locally…