# Python - Tweepy module has incorrect syntax

Tags: python, module, tweepy

I am new to Python and I'd like to import tweepy in an app of mine.
I run this code (taken from [Tweepy official documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/getting_started.html)):

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print tweet.text
```

it returns this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TwitterPythonAnalytics/file3.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       import tweepy   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TwitterPythonAnalytics\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy__init__.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       from tweepy.streaming import Stream, StreamListener   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TwitterPythonAnalytics\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py",
>   line 358
>       def _start(self, async):
>                            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I tried everything to fix indentations and spaces in my .py file, but apparently the problem seems to be inside the Tweepy modules. Can anybody help me to solve this please?

Comment: What Python version are you on?

Comment: I am currently on 3.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tweepy won't install on python 3.7; shows "syntax error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413816/tweepy-wont-install-on-python-3-7-shows-syntax-error)

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't solve my issue. It reinstalled 3.6.0 tweepy version.

Comment: If you reinstall tweepy with ```pip install git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy``` as suggested [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/1042) do you still get a SyntaxError?

Comment: Yes. I managed to solve by reinstalling Python at 3.6 version.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `print tweet.text` in Python 3, I think that's what's happening.

It should be `print(tweet.text)`.

Comment: That's not the problem. I fixed it in the IDE, but that's not the error been caught.

Answer (score 0):

This library has been written by professional coders, So the problem probably is the version of your python or most likely the library that you downloaded.Your python version is probably 2 because of the syntax in your question and the library must be written in 3.
So it is much better to use pip service to get your libraries.
Or You can just run this code :

```
import pip 
pip.main(["install","tweepy"])
```

In both ways you can get a version of that library that you can use.
With all that I recommend installing the python 3.

Comment: I had tweepy installed by cmd with command `pip install tweepy`, so I already tried that. How can I fix this version problem otherwise?

Comment: I downloaded the library using pip and it imports it without any problem.Did you uninstall the package before using pip?

Comment: Yes, me too. But the problem is not in the import, it's when I run the app that it shows the "syntax" error

Comment: In witch line exactly?